# Getting Subject Alternative Name OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, x509certificate, tls1.2, subject-alternative-name

I am attempting to retrieve the subject alternative name from my client certificate. By running this command, I can see the SAN:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in certname.cert.pem
...
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
IP Address:10.10.10.10
```

In a C file, I am trying to retrieve the client SAN, so that I can validate it with the server IP. Here is my attempt:

```
cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(x509Ctx);
int i;
int san_names_nb = -1;
STACK_OF(GENERAL_NAME) *san_names = NULL;

// Try to extract the names within the SAN extension from the certificate
san_names = (GENERAL_NAME*)X509_get_ext_d2i((X509 *) cert, NID_subject_alt_name, NULL, NULL);
if (san_names == NULL) 
{
   return Error;
}
```

Right now, my code is returning the error because san_names is NULL. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSSL command itself gives the SAN as Null

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: **<BLANK>**
IP Address:10.10.10.10
```

Can you just open the certificate and see if it contains the SAN. If not you will have to ask the team to add the SAN and create a new certificate again.

[image]

Comment: The question already states "By running this command, I can see the SAN".

Comment: The IP address was visible and not the SAM so thought its blank

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `X509_get_ext_d2i()`.  Per [the OpenSSL documentation for `X509_get_ext_d2i()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/X509_get_ext_d2i.html) (bolding mine):

> If `idx` is `NULL` then **only one occurrence of an extension is permissible** otherwise the first extension after index `*idx` is returned and `*idx` updated to the location of the extension.

Depending on the version of OpenSSL you're using, the behavior might be slightly different.  The above is the documented behavior for OpenSSL 1.1.0.

Since you are passing `NULL` as `idx`, if there's more than one SAN on the cert you'll get `NULL` from `X509_get_ext_d2i()`.

You can get the OpenSSL error code with [`ERR_get_error()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/ERR_get_error.html).